# Access to object variables in function passed as parameter

Tags: javascript

got an issue with accessing an object parameter in a function of the object if I pass this function as parameter and then call it.I.e. in below code I had expected that `this.radius == 100` is always true. Hover in `test3` below it is not if beforehand I pass `test3` as parameter. Any idea why and how I can access the variable there?

Cheers
Tom

```
Test = function ( ) {
    var self = this;

    this.radius = 100;
    this.test1();
}
Test.prototype.test1 = function() {
    console.log("test1 - this"+this.radius);// this.radius==100
    console.log("test1 - self"+self.radius);// self.radius==undefined
    this.test2(this.test3);
}

Test.prototype.test2 = function (func){
    console.log("test2- this"+this.radius);// this.radius==100
    console.log("test2- self"+self.radius);// self.radius==undefined
    func();// calling the function passed as parameter
}

Test.prototype.test3 = function (){
    console.log("test3- this"+this.radius);// this.radius==undefined
    console.log("test3- self"+self.radius);// self.radius==undefined
}
```

Comment: `this` in `test3` isn't what you think it is, when you call the function with a different context. Notice also, that functions in prototypes can't access local variables in `Test`, i.e. `self` refers to `window` in the methods.

Comment: You need to use `this.test3.bind(this)` so that it keeps its context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function only gets its context from the value before the `.` if you *call* the function that way, i.e. you write `this.test3()`. Creating a function reference with `this.test3` doesn't bind the context. To do that, you need to call `.bind()` explicitly:

```
this.test2(this.test3.bind(this));
```